# .X3D file exported from blender has a black background I cant change

Tags: php, html, css, blender, x3dom

I am integrating a 3d model into a website but I am having an issue where the .X3D file has a solid black background and I cant seem to change it.
I have set the background to white with a strength of 0 in an attempt to get a transparent background but that did not work. I changed the strength to 1 in order to get a white background but that also did not work.
Setting the background in CSS also did not work.
This is with the latest version of blender and X3Dom.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the global background color of your Blender project and do the export again (World -> Horizon Color).